# FancyBox com tamanho dinâmico

Tags: iframe, fancybox

Olá. Já procurei diversos exemplos de como chamar um Pop-up Fancybox passando o tamanho da janela por parâmetros na minha function.

Ex.

```js
AbrirPopUp(url,w, h)
{
    chamar #Fancybox(url,w,h)
}
```

```html
<a href="Javascript:AbrirPopUp("janela1.htm",700,500)">Janela 1</a>

<a href="Javascript:AbrirPopUp("janela2.htm",900,400)">Janela 2</a>

<a href="Javascript:AbrirPopUp("janela3.htm",400,100)">Janela 3</a>
```

Comment: O que foi que deu errado? O que foi que você tentou fazer que não deu certo?

Answer (score 2):

No seu link o nome do arquivo deve estar com aspas simples, as medidas dos parâmetros, também devem estar com aspas simples, e deve conter a unidade de medida, no exemplo a baixo pixel

`<a href="Javascript:AbrirPopUp('janela1.htm',700px,500px)">Janela 1</a>`

chame o fancybox em sua function passando os parâmetros

```
<script>
    function AbrirPopUp (url, w, h) {
        $(".fast_edit").fancybox({
            href            : url,
            autoSize        : false, 
            fitToView       : false,
            width           : w,
            height          : h
        });
    }
</script>
```